# Calculate Monthly Amount Using Daily Rates and Start/End + Rate Change Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

O365 Excel 2305

[image: data]

Table to copy/paste in B2

|  |  | reg2 start | 4/14/2024 |  | Regular |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | special2 start | 1/1/2024 |  | Special |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| start date | end date | type | daily1 | daily2 | 7/31/2023 | 8/31/2023 | 9/30/2023 | 10/31/2023 | 11/30/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 1/31/2024 | 2/29/2024 | 3/31/2024 | 4/30/2024 | 5/31/2024 | 6/30/2024 |
| 9/12/2023 | 6/30/2024 | Regular | 100 | 120 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7/1/2023 | 3/3/2024 | Regular | 100 | 120 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11/14/2023 | 6/30/2024 | Special | 80 | 110 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7/1/2023 | 10/5/2023 | Special | 80 | 110 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

G7 formula below:

```
=IF($D7=$G$2,
((MAX(G$6-$B7,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$B7,0))
-(MAX(G$6-$E$2,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$E$2,0))
+(G$6=$B7))*$E7
+((MAX(G$6-$E$2,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$E$2,0))
-(MAX(G$6-$C7,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$C7,0))
+(G$6=$B7))*$F7,
((MAX(G$6-$B7,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$B7,0))
-(MAX(G$6-$E$3,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$E$3,0))
+(G$6=$B7))*$E7
+((MAX(G$6-$E$3,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$E$3,0))
-(MAX(G$6-$C7,0)-MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)-$C7,0))
+(G$6=$B7))*$F7)
```

G7 would calculate:

Days at Rate1 * DailyRate1 + Days at Rate2 * DailyRate2

Rate2 starts on a different date for "Regular" Type vs "Special" Type

Struggling to incorporate the End Date (as seen by negative amounts).

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You could simplify this formula but moving the `IF()` function inside the formula. `IF()` in an Excel worksheet is a function not a statement so it does not necessarily need to be at the start of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
=IF($D7=$G$2,
$E7*SUMPRODUCT((--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<=G$6))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0))>=(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<$E$2)))+
$F7*SUMPRODUCT((--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<=G$6))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0))>=(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)>=$E$2))),
$E7*SUMPRODUCT((--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<=G$6))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0))>=(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<$E$3)))+
$F7*SUMPRODUCT((--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)<=G$6))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0))>=(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1))*(--($B7+SEQUENCE(1+$C7-$B7,,0)>=$E$3))))
```

SUMPRODUCT to the rescue. Created an array of active days with SEQUENCE using start/end dates. Filtered the array using SUMPRODUCT to count only days in the Month. Filtered the array again to count only days before Rate Change date. Multiplied it by Rate1. Repeated it but for days after and including Rate Change date. Multiplied it by Rate2. Used IF to tell it which Rate Change date to use.

Answer (score 0):

This formula for cell `G7`

```
=MAX(0,
     MIN(G$6,$C7,IF($D7=$G$2,$E$2,$E$3)-1)- 
     MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1,$B7)
     +1
    )*$E7 +
 MAX(0,
     MIN(G$6,$C7)- 
     MAX(EOMONTH(G$6,-1)+1,$B7,IF($D7=$G$2,$E$2,$E$3))
     +1
    )*$F7
```

gives results consistent with the correct values in the OP when extended to the other cells.

It is based on finding the start and end points of potentially overlapping periods of:

- a calendar month
- the period defined by the start and end dates in columns `D` and `E`
- EITHER the period before the changeover date (given in range `E2:E3`) OR the period on or after the changeover date

The start point of any overlapping period is the latest of the 3 start points of the 3 individual periods. Similarly, the end point is the earliest of the 3 end points of the individual periods. If the start point is after the end point then there is no overlap.